# Given a recursive program with the following recurrence relation?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, algorithms, recurrence-relations, mathematical-modeling

Given a recursive program with the following recurrence relation:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
{C_n} = 3{C_{\frac{n}{3}}} + 1,n > 1\\
{C_1} = 1
\end{array}
$$
Solve the recurrence relation to find the complexity of the program

I have a solution by placing sub-hidden as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
{C_n} = 3{C_{\frac{n}{3}}} + 1\\
 \Rightarrow {C_{{3^k}}} = 3{C_{{3^{k - 1}}}} + 1\\
 \Leftrightarrow {C_{{3^k}}} = 3\left( {3{C_{{3^{k - 2}}}} + 1} \right) + 1 = {3^2}{C_{{3^{k - 2}}}} + 3 + 1\\
 \Leftrightarrow {C_{{3^k}}} = {3^2}\left( {3{C_{{3^{k - 3}}}} + 1} \right) + 3 + 1 = {3^3}{C_{{3^{k - 3}}}} + {3^2} + 3 + 1\\
 \Leftrightarrow {C_{{3^k}}} = ...\\
 \Leftrightarrow {C_{{3^k}}} = {3^k}{C_1} + {3^{k - 1}} + ... + {3^2} + 3 + 1 = {3^k} + {3^k} - 1 = {3^{k}} +\frac{{{3^k} - 1}}{2}\\
{C_n} = \frac{{3n}}{2} - \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
$$
Complexity of the program ${\rm O}(n)$

I want to ask everyone if there is any other solution method that directly uses integer values of $n$ without sub-implicit, a general solution

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: The problem statement is incomplete. What would be the $\tfrac n3$ index for $n$ not divisible by $3$? E.g. what is $C_2$ or $C_4$?

Answer (score 1):

As

$$
C\left(3^{\log_3 n}\right) = 3C\left(3^{\log_3 \frac n3}\right) + 1
$$

making $\mathcal{C}(\cdot) = C\left(3^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_3 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{C}(z) = 3\mathcal{C}(z-1)+1
$$

recurrence with solution

$$
\mathcal{C}(z) = 3^{z-1}c_0 + \frac 12(3^z-1)
$$

now going backwards with $z = \log_3 n$ we have finally

$$
C(n) = \frac n3 c_0 +\frac 12(n-1)
$$

or considering that $C(1) = 1$

$$
C(n) = \frac 12(3n-1)
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I have some questions.
What is the idea of this transformation $C\left(  \right) = C\left( {{3^{\left(  \right)}}} \right)$ , can you explain more?
And I would like to tweak your answer a little bit
$C\left( n \right) = n + \frac{1}{2}\left( {n - 1} \right)$

Comment: $\mathcal{C}\left(\cdot \right) = C\left(3^{\left( \cdot \right)}\right)$: note that $\mathcal{C}(\cdot ) \ne C(\cdot)$ so $\mathcal{C}(\cdot ) $ and $ C(\cdot)$ are different functions. The linear recurrence is for $\mathcal{C}(\cdot ) $.